# How to get URL variable that already encode using encodeURI() using $_GET

Tags: javascript, php, get

I have a variable that I need to pass to 2nd page using URL, I used javascript encodeURI() for the variable.

For example in 1st page, I did enter `test & test` in my title. And in the 2nd page, the variable in the URL will look like this

```
http://localhost/schedule/sc_add_planresult.php?isallday=0&title=test%20&%20test
```

In my 1st page, I'm using:

```
var eurl="sc_add_planresult.php?isallday="+id+"&title="+data[2];
window.open(encodeURI(eurl), "_self");`
```

My question is, how can I `$_GET` the variable so that I can get the full words 'test & test'?

Here is my get statement:

```
$schTitle = isset($_GET['title']) ? $_GET['title'] : null;
```

I did try to use:

```
$schTitle = rawurlencode($_GET['title']));
$schTitle = isset($_GET['title']) ? $_GET['title'] : null;
$schTitle =urldecode($varr);
```

but still either it either gives an error or the title is only display as "test".

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) and [`urldecode`](http://php.net/urldecode), so:

```
$schTitle = isset($_GET['title']) ? $_GET['title'] : null;
$schTitle = urlencode($_GET['title']);

echo 'http://localhost/schedule/sc_add_planresult.php?isallday=0&title=' . $schTitle;
```

Then to decode, use:

```
$title = urldecode($_GET['title']);
```

Comment: but in my first page I used javascript to pass the URL, is it possible to pass using javascript and get it using php?

Comment: Via an AJAX call, perhaps. Or using a regular expression and replace.